# Login template cached for other action when session timeout in Symfony

Tags: caching, authentication, symfony1, routes, symfony-1.4

I am using Symfony 1.4 with sfGuardDoctrinePlugin. The problem is:

- Lets us say the current page URL is www.pg.com/blog/edit.php
- Now the session times-out and I click the blog index link
- This redirects to www.pg.com/blog but since I need to login, the template for login_module and login_action is served on the same URL (www.pg.com/blog)
- Post login, the user is taken to blog index (or even if the user clicks that link), the login template is served since it is cached for the "blog/index".

I suspect that somewhere in sfAuth plugin, there is a forward instead of a redirect that is serving the login template on the other page URL. **How can I prevent this?**

**EDIT:** I even got the line where it is happening, but I do not wish to modify Symfony source code. Can I do it outside?

```
Jul 31 10:02:59 symfony [info] {sfBasicSecurityFilter} Action "blog/index" requires authentication, forwarding to "sfGuardAuth/signin"
```

The user has to wait for quite some time or clear cache to avoid this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forwarding is done by the `sfBasicSecurityFilter` filter. If you want to change the forward to a redirect, you will have to overwrite the `forwardToLoginAction` in your own security filter:

```
class mySecurityFilter extends sfBasicSecurityFilter
{

   protected function forwardToLoginAction()
   {
       $this->getContext()->getController()->redirect(sfConfig::get('sf_login_module') . '/' . sfConfig::get('sf_login_action'));
       throw new sfStopException();
   }
 }
```

Comment: thanks, look like it'll work - I will try it soon. I might be getting a little greedy here: but have you figured out a way to retain the referrer and send the user back there post login? thru query parameter?

Comment: If you don't specify a value for `sf_guard_plugin_success_signin_url` in config.yml, sfGuardDoctrinePlugin look at the referer to redirect the user after signin, so you don't have to do anything ;)

Comment: thanks a ton; will verify & accept tomorrw; little tied up today

Comment: your piece of advice works 100%, thanks. It still won't redirect to the referrer :( where can I find the config.yml that you mentioned?

Comment: Just verify you don't have any `sf_guard_plugin_success_signin_url` defined in the config.yml file. This config variable allow you to indicate a route where to redirect the user after login. If none is set the plugin get the referer of the user to redirect him. This is at the end of the function `executeSignin` in `plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPLugin/modules/sfGuardAuth/lib/BasesfGuardAuthActions.class.php`.